# java - why does this byte cause no exception?

Tags: java, primitive

I initialized a byte as follows:

```
byte b = (byte) 0b11110000000;
```

Since a byte is 8 bits of size, I was expecting that it would throw some exception or error, since this number should be assignable only to a short or above. Still it evaluated to -124? Or is this perhaps the "normal" behavior? (no exception thrown, but variable is overflown)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be getting `-128`.

When you explicitly cast an `int` to `byte`, the lowest 8 bits are taken, and the rest are discarded.

In your example the lowest 8 bits are `10000000`, and the decimal value of that number is `-128`.

Without the explicit cast, the code won't pass compilation, since your assignment causes a loss of information.

Comment: So yes: It is "*normal*" behavior. But I don't know why they designed it this way, anyone an idea?

Comment: @Zabuza Well, if you are only interested in the lowest 8 bits of an `int`, you can assign them to a `byte` using this explicit cast. Just like if you are only interested in the integer part of a `double` of `float`, you can explicitly cast it to `int` (or `long`) and discard the fraction part.

Comment: Ah, with the comparison it sounds meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the error, get rid of the cast.

```
byte b = 0b11110000000;
```

That will give you "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte."

Since you're explicitly casting that value with `(byte)`, the Java compiler assumes you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
byte b = (byte) 0b11110000000;
```

`0b11110000000` is an `int` literal that is narrowing converted to a `byte`.

A byte is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
Its minimum value is -128 and its maximum value is 127.
The maximum value in byte representation is

```
 1111111
```

And

```
10000000
```

overflows the max value of 1.
So, it overflows to the next value that is the minimal value of byte : `-128`

Answer (score 0):

remember that you are casting:

```
(byte) 0b11110000000;
```

everything else after (MSB) the bit 8 will be discarded...

that means: alll the following byte initializations will be trucated to -128 (**1000_0000** or the 1st 8 bits)

```
byte b = (byte) 0b1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000;
System.out.println(b);

// even here with longs as bin
b = (byte) 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000L;
System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is called Widening Primitive Conversion.

5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion

19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

byte to short, int, long, float, or double

For details, you may refer to this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html